# little confusing regex in java

Tags: java, regex

There is a string in log file like that :

```
'AUR   HALAA /PART="CMF1_SAS_PROJECT" /ROLE="VR_ANALYST" /TY=C /CAP=S /DEL' (S)
```

`'AUR and /ROLE=""`  are a constant part

`HALAA and VR_ANALYST` are inputs

My Regex is : `"^'AUR (\\w+) .*? /ROLE=\"(\\w+)\".*$";`

But it doesn't work correctly. Could some one show me the correct regex for this sentence please ?

Comment: here is online regex tester. Try to experiment there. http://regexpal.com/

Comment: In addition to @Antoniossss I can also recommend http://www.regexplanet.com/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is more than one space after `'AUR` - you need to allow the regex to match that, too:

```
"^'AUR +(\\w+) .*? /ROLE=\"(\\w+)\".*$";
```

You should use the `.find()` method, not `matches()`, because your string (if it's from a logfile) likely contains a newline at the end, and the `.*` won't match that. Plus, the anchors would be unnecessary in that case. So, try this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^'AUR +(\\w+) .*? /ROLE=\"(\\w+)\".*$");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(strLine);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    first = regexMatcher.group(1);
    second = regexMatcher.group(2); 
}
```

Comment: When I try your regex without parameters like 
`"^'AUR +(HALAA) .*? /ROLE=\"(VR_ANALYST)\".*$"` 
It is still doesn't match :/

Comment: The regex does match. You might be using it wrong. How are you performing the match?

Comment: `String reg = "^'AUR +(HALAA) .*? /ROLE=\\\"(VR_ANALYST)\\\".*$";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(reg);
if(regex.matcher(strLine).matches())`

Comment: OK, and how are you performing the match? So far, you've only compiled a regex, not used it.

Comment: I forget to added on that part, I editted my previous comment and also add that part to here.

`if(regex.matcher(strLine).matches())`

Comment: OK, and the `if` returns `False`? Does `strLine` contain anything else besides the text in your example? A newline, perhaps? The fact that you're using `matches()` instead of `find()` makes me wonder about that, especially since you're also using anchors in your regex. Oh, and why the triple backslashes? That's different from the regex in your question (and my answer). I'll edit my post to make this clearer.

Comment: ahhhhh ,I am sorry for my careless, there is a \t before my logfile so 
i change the regex like that `"\\t'AUR +(\\w+) .*? /ROLE=\"(\\w+)\".*$";` and everything is okay right now. 
But i have more one question, how can i give the inputs to this regex ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
^'AUR\s*\w*.*/ROLE="\w*".*
```